# Azure resource visualizer API to generate SVG or PNG?

Tags: azure-rest-api, azure-resource-graph

Is there any Azure Rest API to get the Resource visualizer in the SVG or PNG format?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such API and the diagram is generated client side based on relationships that is determined in the resource object.

Answer (score 0):

This can be automated using PowerShell module called 'AzViz', check this out - https://ridicurious.com/2021/04/08/automated-azure-infrastructure-diagrams-with-powershell/

On top of what azure provides today, its more customizable and not limited to network topology but can map resource dependencies as well.

You can wrap this module in an API and it should work.